# AWS Backupvault SNS notification

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns, aws-backup

I have created a backup plan and configured SNS using cloud formation ( not CLI ), but backup job has running and completed successfully but not receiving emails notification ( already subscribe to the SNS topic ).

**Backup vault section in cloudformation :**

```html
BackupVaultWithDailyBackupssns:
    Type: "AWS::Backup::BackupVault"
    Properties:
      BackupVaultName: "Vault_name"
      Notifications:      
          BackupVaultEvents:
            - BACKUP_JOB_STARTED
            - BACKUP_JOB_COMPLETED
            - BACKUP_JOB_SUCCESSFUL
            - BACKUP_JOB_FAILED
          SNSTopicArn:
            !Sub 'arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:My_topic'
```

**SNS Policy :**

```html
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:Subscribe",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:Publish",
        "SNS:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:My_topic",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "111111111"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "My-statement-id",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "backup.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:My_topic"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: SNS topic reference :   https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aws-backup-failed-job-notification/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer on this here I how I set mine up, this is working for all failed notifications.

Set up your vault referencing a topic

```
  BackupVault:
    Type: "AWS::Backup::BackupVault"
    Properties:
      BackupVaultName: Backup Vault Name
      Notifications:
        BackupVaultEvents:
          - "BACKUP_JOB_EXPIRED"
          - "BACKUP_JOB_FAILED"
        SNSTopicArn: !Ref FailedBackupTopic
    DependsOn:
      - FailedBackupTopic
```

Set up a topic, topic policy and topic subscription

```
  FailedBackupTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName: "AWS Backup - Failed backup notification"

  FailedBackupTopicPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy'
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Id: SNSPolicyV1
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Sid: Sid1
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - 'backup.amazonaws.com'
            Action: 'sns:Publish'
            Resource: !Ref FailedBackupTopic
      Topics:
        - !Ref FailedBackupTopic

  FailedBackupTopicSubscription:
    Type: 'AWS::SNS::Subscription'
    Properties:
      Endpoint: "email@email.com"
      Protocol: email
      TopicArn: !Ref FailedBackupTopic
```